# How can i limit the char number in my CC details on android

Tags: android

I have my checkout form here https://bookretreats.com/200hrs-tantra-hatha-yoga-teacher-training-with-jason-jessica-january-2017 > click on reserve and you will see the form.

On desktop, it works perfect, but i cant seem to find a solution for how to limit the chars on android mobile.

Would love to get a direction.

Thanks,
Ron.

Answer (score 1):

In XML add this line to the EditText View where 20 is the maximum number of characters:

```
android:maxLength="20"
```

These might help:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20200222150701/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/02/maxlength-in-edittext-using-codes.html
- https://web.archive.org/web/20181018065751/http://anddev.org/edit_text_max_limit_charactars-t1925.html